# Why the global variables info is not shown for Arduino Due in IDE?

Tags: arduino-due, memory-usage, ide

If I compile a sketch for the Arduino Mega:

```
Sketch uses 1804 bytes (0%) of program storage space. Maximum is 253952 bytes.
Global variables use 188 bytes (2%) of dynamic memory, 
leaving 8004 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 8192 bytes.
```

If I compile the same sketch for the Arduino Due:

```
Sketch uses 26304 bytes (5%) of program storage space. Maximum is 524288 bytes.
```

Why is the global variables part not supported for the Due, it seems to me it's quite important (even more than the sketch size).

Or can I enable this option somehow? (and if yes, how)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a difference in how the build system calculates the memory size for AVR and SAM. The platform.txt file contains the rule for calculating the size. There is a difference how this is done for SAM (Arduino Due).

The AVR size rules (https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-avr/blob/master/platform.txt#L79) are:

```
## Compute size
recipe.size.pattern="{compiler.path}{compiler.size.cmd}" -A "{build.path}/{build.project_name}.elf"
recipe.size.regex=^(?:\.text|\.data|\.bootloader)\s+([0-9]+).*
recipe.size.regex.data=^(?:\.data|\.bss|\.noinit)\s+([0-9]+).*
recipe.size.regex.eeprom=^(?:\.eeprom)\s+([0-9]+).*
```

And the rules for SAM (https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-sam/blob/master/platform.txt#L91) are:

```
recipe.size.pattern="{compiler.path}{compiler.size.cmd}" -A "{build.path}/{build.project_name}.elf"
recipe.size.regex=\.text\s+([0-9]+).*
```

They may be updated to give more information about the memory size. A good reference on the subject is http://www.support.code-red-tech.com/CodeRedWiki/FlashRamSize which shows that the output from size command for SAM contains much more information.

I assume that from the above information you see how this could be updated.

Cheers!

Comment: Thank you very much ... that output looks very much to what I get when I compile software for the STM32. However, I tried to find how to run arm-none-eabi-nm -S --size-sort -s project.axf, but I cannot find the axf file and there is - at least no menu option - to  run arm-none-eabi-nm